# Multiple Modally Presented (page sheet) ViewControllers Navigation Item Bug

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

iOS 13. The problem is shown on the screenshot.

[image: gap under navigation item]

The steps are:

1. Open one view controller modally with page sheet style.
2. Open another (second) view controller modally with page sheet style.

Expected: no Nav Bar bug

Actual: see screenshot

The source code is available here: https://github.com/rinat-enikeev/NavBarBug

Question: how to fix this bug? I want to present 2 view controllers modally with page sheet style.

Comment: i my opinion this is an Apple Bug. Just a proposal for solution: if you move the barButtons to the left, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who faced the same issue. The workaround is to add the following code to the viewDidLoad method:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
}
```