# iOS 13 navigation bar issue - part of navigation bar becomes transparent

Tags: navigationbar, ios13, modalviewcontroller, xcode11

[image]

My app running on iOS 13 shows weird appearance.
When a form sheet is presented on another form sheet, part of navigation bar becomes transparent so that you can see another form sheet beneath it.

When my app enter background and come back to foreground, the navigation bar come back to normal navigation bar as it should be.

This error does not appear on the firstly presented form sheet. 
Only appears from the second form sheet (form sheet over another form sheet)

Anyone has had same issue?
Any solutions?

iOS 13.2 - XCode 11.2

Comment: Hi. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266232/multiple-modally-presented-page-sheet-viewcontrollers-navigation-item-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to add the following code to the viewDidLoad method:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
}
```

Comment: Thank. This works. Additionally, I had to configure the navigation bar appearance as for my own needs.